# Vuex: How to update component data or call component methods from Store

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

If I have a store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    foo: bar
  },
  mutations: {
    updateComponent (state) {
      // computation and logic
      // update state
      this.$refs.myComponent.updateComponent(state.foo)
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a component with ref 'myComponent':

```
<template>
  ...
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    ...
    methods: {
      updateComponent(payload) {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would like to call the 'updateComponent()' method from the store. I can use `this.$refs.myComponent` from other views and components, but it doesn't work from the Store. I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'myComponent' of undefined`.

Clearly `this` is not the correct scope for the `this.$refs.myComponent` when using from the Store.

Can I call `updateComponent()` from my store mutation, and how?

Comment: I'm not understanding what the purpose of the call to the store is if it isn't manipulating store state, why not just update the component locally?

Comment: @jacob13smith In the real scenario there's a bunch of computation going on in the mutation, after which state is updated, and then the component needs to update itself based on state. I could get around this another way, e.g. watcher, but wondered if this is possible?

Comment: You could also use [Subscribe to store mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe)

Comment: You could create a **getter** or just **this.$store.state.something** in a **computed**. Wouldn't that be what you're looking for? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `vuex`'s subscribe method.  Subscribe your component in it's mounted phase:

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        switch(mutation.type) {
          case 'updateComponent':
            // Update your component with new state data
          break;
        } 
     })
  }
```

Reference: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe

Comment: Thanks. This should do the trick. I'll try it out and mark as correct. A question, though: Why the switch statement? Is that to manage the possibility of subscribing to multiple mutations?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the subscribe method will trigger on every mutation, you could just use an `if` statement if there is only one mutation you want to subscribe to.